How to configure spring cloud contract stub runner to fetch contracts from a remote repository?
I am working with Spring Cloud contract to verify the consumer with the producer contract.
When I fetch the producer contracts locally, everything works.
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.per.adoption:support.users:+:8081",
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)

The problem arises when I try to fetch the contracts from a remote repository, which the following configuration
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.per.adoption:support.users:+:8081",
        repositoryRoot = "git://https://github.com/davidcediel12/pet-adoption-contracts",
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE)

The repository where the contracts are is: this one, you can check it.
It throws the following error.
Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception with message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to delete base directory

This is the full error message:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception with message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to delete base directory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:277) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:806) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:194) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1709) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:556) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:782) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:119) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:119) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]

This is my build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '7.7.0'
}

group = 'com.pet.adoption.support'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(22)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers'
    testImplementation 'com.redis:testcontainers-redis:2.2.2'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    implementation 'com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates:3.14.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set('java')
    configOptions.set([
            library: 'restclient',
            openApiNullable: 'false'
    ])
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/contracts/client/openapi-support-users.yaml".toString()
    ignoreFileOverride = ".openapi-generator-java-sources.ignore"
    invokerPackage = 'com.pet.adoption.business.user.client'
    modelPackage = 'com.pet.adoption.business.user.client.model'
    apiPackage = 'com.pet.adoption.business.user.client.api'

}

tasks.named('compileJava'){
    dependsOn(tasks.openApiGenerate)
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir layout.buildDirectory.dir("/generate-resources/main/src/main/java")

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


This is my test class
package com.pet.adoption.business.user.controller;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.pet.adoption.business.user.dto.AuthStep;
import com.pet.adoption.business.user.dto.UserRequest;
import com.redis.testcontainers.RedisContainer;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.AutoConfigureStubRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.HashOperations;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.pet.adoption.business.user.util.Constants.USER_REQUEST;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.per.adoption:support.users:+:8081",
        repositoryRoot = "git://https://github.com/davidcediel12/pet-adoption-contracts",
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE)
class UserControllerIntegrationTest {

    static RedisContainer redis = new RedisContainer(DockerImageName.parse("redis:7-alpine"));

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        redis.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() {
        redis.stop();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + port;
        Objects.requireNonNull(redisTemplate.keys("*")).forEach(redisTemplate::delete);
    }


    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.redis.host", redis::getRedisHost);
        registry.add("spring.data.redis.port", redis::getRedisPort);
    }


    @Test
    void shouldSaveUserInCacheWhenSignInAttempt() {

        UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest(AuthStep.PRE_TOKEN_ISSUANCE,
                USER_REQUEST.clientId(), USER_REQUEST.email(), USER_REQUEST.displayName(), USER_REQUEST.country(),
                USER_REQUEST.role(), USER_REQUEST.postalCode());

        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(userRequest)
                .when()
                .post("/users")
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());


        Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys("*");
        assertThat(keys).hasSize(1);

        String key = keys.iterator().next();

        HashOperations<String, String, String> hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
        String user = hashOperations.get(key, "user");

        DocumentContext savedUser = JsonPath.parse(user);

        String userName = savedUser.read("$.displayName");

        assertThat(userName).isEqualTo(USER_REQUEST.displayName());
    }


    @Test
    void shouldSaveUserInDatabaseWhenSignUpAttempt() {
        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(USER_REQUEST)
                .when()
                .post("/users")
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());

        assertThat(redisTemplate.keys("*")).isEmpty();
    }


}

I'm trying to configure spring cloud contract to obtain the contracts from a remote repository, I expect that the test can obtain these contracts and run it

Finally, I found the error.
The problem is that the Spring Cloud Contract by default searches in the branch  master, so If you want to specify another one, according to the documentation You can specify the branch name like this:
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.per.adoption:support.users:+:8081",
    repositoryRoot = "git://https://github.com/davidcediel12/pet-adoption-contracts.git",
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE,
    properties = {"git.branch=main"})

